# Fourier Transform of a continous time truncated Random Process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I was reading about PSD from:

http://www.comm.toronto.edu/frank/notes/wk.pdf

It goes to "prove" the Wiener-Khinchin theorem but it's not clear to me how you can take the Fourier Transform of a continuous time random process. A specific realization of the random process may not be integrable(as far as I know),

Could someone explain what's going on?

Comment: it looks like the proof you linked supposes that the Fourier Transform exists.

Comment: I'm not even sure if it's integrating a realization of the process or not. Is it using the standard Riemann integral?

Comment: Parzen - Stochastic Processes has a whole section on the Spectral Density that is fairly readable. https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971125?mobileUi=0